# Ember. Live uploading templates

Tags: templates, ember.js, live

I want uploading ember templates from server.
I seen for that need used like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url_to_template_text',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (resp) {
        App.AboutView = Ember.View.extend({
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(resp)
        });   
    }
});
```

but i cant understand how rendering this view on page.
App.AboutView.append() - is not worked

if add routing for that view, then do not have time to render getting template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
   {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    That text cant be show
</script>

//////JS

$.ajax({
    url: 'url_to_template_text',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (resp) {

        App.AboutView = Ember.View.extend({
            templateName: 'about',
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(resp)
        });

    }
});


App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("about", { path: "/" });   
});
```

Not worked too. Is rendering oldest template content(i mean "That text cant be show")

Please help me, perhaps i used bad way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `beforeModel` hook to load the template alongside the `model` hook. In this case it appears you also want to use it to resolve as the default view for the route. You can do this using the Ember conventions, AboutRoute -> AboutView -> AboutController, etc.

```
beforeModel: function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/about.hbs'
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    Em.TEMPLATES.about = Em.Handlebars.compile(response);
  });
},
```

After you load the template you need to assign it to the global `Ember.TEMPLATES` object.

Another approach, is to do the same for a view's template. By reopening the View's class and adding the loaded template as you do above. Note, you still have to use the view inside your handlebars template with `{{view App.MyView}}`.

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/owuwab/2/) example.